# backuppc similar software?

Tags: backup, raid, network-attached-storage

I have been using backuppc backup software and really like it, but due to it's use of hard links (and possible other issues?) it will only run under linux and will not work with certain file systems, NAS or RAID technologies such as FlexRaid or anything Windows.

Anyone know of a backup software that works similar to this- they KEY points are that it does not require an agent to back up windows pc's.  It uses the SMB IPC share  (C$).  Also, it supports data de-duplication and even file compression to save space on the backup server.

Bacula supports data de-dup and sort-of supports smb backups without an agent, but I have been finding bacula VERY complicated to setup.

Amanda looks like it does not support data de-dup and not sure about smb?

Anything similar out there?

Comment: Perhaps something mentioned [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/15974) will fit your needs.

Comment: why you need to use obsolete 'certain file systems, NAS or RAID technologies such as FlexRaid or anything Windows' and not a standard POSIX filesystem? In other words, maybe you shouldn’t find an alternative backup solutions but an alternative effective storage solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for free/cheap?  Try [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm).

Comment: but this looks like a single machine backup software.   I am looking to set up a backup server software and back up remote clients.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the request.  Amanda or Bacula will do pull backups over CIFS, but as you mentioned, they have a learning curve & require a linux server.  I'm sure there are others but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: the link is not valid